# Can updates be made to "ogr_fdw" foreign tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sql-server, ogr, fdw

I am accessing a Microsoft SQL Server table (w/ SQL Server a geometry column) via an ogr_fdw foreign table. SELECT statements work great, including the PostGIS functions that I've tried.

Are UPDATES (and INSERTS/DELETES) supported?

I receive an error:  `ERROR: cannot update foreign table... "`, is that a limitation of the ogr_fdw or fdw in general?

Or is it supported and I need to do additional configuration to the foreign table?

```
CREATE SERVER dev_db_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER ogr_fdw
  OPTIONS (
    datasource 'MSSQL:server=...',
    format 'MSSQLSpatial' );



CREATE FOREIGN TABLE xxxtable(
---
 )
 SERVER dev_db_server
 OPTIONS ( layer 'xxxtable' );
```

'2.2 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1'

'PostgreSQL 9.5beta2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit'

Answer (score 1):

Its a limitation of ogr_fdw. Many ogr drivers doesn't support writing, so the developers left writing out for now.